# Scratch + GPIO + Adafruit MotorHAT

Tags: raspberry-pi, gpio, mit-scratch, adafruit

I have a Raspberry PI2 with Adafruit MotorHAT, and two stepper motors attached to the hat. I have installed the Cymplecy GPIO7 on my Raspberry Pi 2, and I tried to control the stepper motors with it, but I cannot. I set the AddOn variable to MotorHAT, and send broadcast message "motor1speed20" but nothing happens.

Does anybody know anything about how to control stepper motors using scratch in such an environment like this? Does GPIO addon supports this adafruit motorhat?

Comment: Just to do some basic troubleshooting...do the motors run from manual control?  Do the motors run from remote control?  If so then the problem is with your program/interface/etc.  If no then the problem could be your basic hardware.  If you don't know then maybe find out.